# Incoherent least cost path

Tags: r, gis, terra

I am having difficulties obtaining a correct least cost path via the command `create_lcp` from the `leastcostpath` package. The problem is documented in the minimum working example hereby.

In particular, the issue arises when I avoid creating a transition layer via `gdistance` and the related `geoCorrection` command, using instead the `create_cs` command from the `leastcostpath` package. This yields a `conductanceMatrix` object starting from some initial cost raster. As documented in the example, the `create_cs` command alters the cost structure contained in the raster, which is a first problem. But even according to such an altered cost structure, the resulting least cost path does not minimize costs.

What am I doing wrong?

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(leastcostpath)

# Create toy cost raster with projected coordinates
nr <- 5
nc <- 3
m <- matrix(
  data = c(1,NA,NA,
           1,1,NA,
           2,3,1,
           1,1,1,
           NA,1,NA),
  nrow = nr,
  ncol = nc,
  byrow = T)

# Cost raster
x0 <- c(1510969,4344218)
cost.r <- rast(
  cost.m,
  extent = ext(c(x0[1],x0[1]+nc,x0[2],x0[2]+nr)),
  crs = "EPSG:3003"
)

# Create conductance matrix via <create_cs>
conductanceMatrix <- create_cs(
  x = cost.r,
  neighbours = 8)
plot(conductanceMatrix)

# Obtain polygons from cells
pgn.inn <- as.polygons(cost.r,
                       aggregate = F,
                       na.rm = T,
                       na.all = T)
pgn.inn <- st_as_sf(pgn.inn)

# Cell centroids
ctr.inn <- st_centroid(pgn.inn)

# Pick two endpoints
endpts <- ctr.inn[c(1,4) ,1]

# LCP
lcp <- create_lcp(conductanceMatrix,
                  endpts[1,],
                  endpts[2,],
                  cost_distance = T)

# Plot
plot(
  conductanceMatrix,
  colNA = NA,
  axes = F,
  box = F,
  legend = T
)
plot(st_as_sfc(pgn.inn), border = "white", lwd = 0.2, add = T)
plot(
  st_as_sfc(lcp),
  col = "black",
  lwd = 2,
  axes = F,
  add = T
)
plot(
  st_as_sfc(endpts),
  pch = 16,
  cex = 1,
  col = "black",
  axes = F,
  add = T
)
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIFI8.png)

I have read in detail the manual of the `leastcostpath` package and I have also looked in the code of its `create_cs` function, but I have not understood what causes the problem described above.

Comment: One thing you could try is to create sample data that fall inside the extent of the CRS you are using. For instance, the extent of conductanceMatrix is `0 3 0 5 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` and that is a long way outside the extent covered by [EPSG:3003](https://epsg.io/3003). You mentioned the choice of CRS in one of your other questions. Large distortions can and most often do occur when applying a CRS to out-of-bounds coordinates. Given your discussions with @JosephLewis, it might not be the only issue, but it's worth eliminating this issue so you can at least rule it out.

Comment: Distorsions associated with projections were my first guess as well, but they do not seem to be the cause of the issue here, as far as I can tell. I have edited the code to ensure that the extent of the cost raster fits within the extent of the CRS, and the problem seems to persist.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks for using the R package *leastcostpath*!

If you have a cost surface you'll need to invert it before supplying it to create_cs(). This function, and the package more generally, works on using conductance values, i.e. higher values are more conductive/less costly.

```
m <- 1/m
```

In terms of create_cs altering the supplied raster, this is only the case when plotting the conductanceMatrix (or using leastcostpath::rasterise). I've tried to explain how this works below. Hopefully this helps.

Using your toy example

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(leastcostpath)

# Create toy cost raster with projected coordinates
nr <- 5
nc <- 3
m <- matrix(
  data = c(1,NA,NA,
           1,1,NA,
           2,3,1,
           1,1,1,
           NA,1,NA),
  nrow = nr,
  ncol = nc,
  byrow = T)

m <- 1/m

cost.r <- rast(m,crs = "EPSG:3003")
plot(cost.r)
#plotted the values in the spatRaster so we can visualise
text(cost.r)

# Create conductance matrix via <create_cs>
conductanceMatrix <- create_cs(
  x = cost.r,
  neighbours = 8)

# the plot() function for a conductanceMatrix mean averages all values going into/out of that cell
# for example, given the neighbourhood of 8 there are 7 cells connected to cell 8 (the central cell with a value of 3). In total, the total conductivity to that central cell is 21 (3*7)
# The central cell is also connected to 7 cells. This time the total conductivity is 8 (1+1+2+1+1+1+1)
# so the average conductance value to the central cell is 3 (21/7, because the total conductance is 21 and there are 7 cels)
# the average conductance from the central cell is 1.142857 (8/7)
# so the average overall is 2.071429 ((3 + 1.142857)/2)
# this is what you see when you plot the conductance matrix
plot(conductanceMatrix)
text(rasterise(conductanceMatrix))

# the actual values are not changed. For example, below shows us conductance to the central cell. We can see that the conductance to that cell is 3 (given that this cell has a conductance of 3 from the supplied spatRaster). Also, the non-zeros show us which cells are connected to the central cell. for example, the first 3 refers to cell 4, (i.e. the cell top-left from the central cell), 4th refers to cell 5 (above central cell, etc)
conductanceMatrix$conductanceMatrix[,8]

# Obtain polygons from cells
pgn.inn <- as.polygons(cost.r,
                       aggregate = F,
                       na.rm = T,
                       na.all = T)
pgn.inn <- st_as_sf(pgn.inn)

# Cell centroids
ctr.inn <- st_centroid(pgn.inn)

# Pick two endpoints
endpts <- ctr.inn[c(1,4) ,1]

# LCP
lcp <- create_lcp(conductanceMatrix,
                  endpts[1,],
                  endpts[2,],
                  cost_distance = T)

# Plot
plot(
  conductanceMatrix,
  colNA = NA,
  axes = F,
  box = F,
  legend = T
)
plot(st_as_sfc(pgn.inn), border = "white", lwd = 0.2, add = T)
plot(
  st_as_sfc(lcp),
  col = "black",
  lwd = 2,
  axes = F,
  add = T
)
plot(
  st_as_sfc(endpts),
  pch = 16,
  cex = 1,
  col = "black",
  axes = F,
  add = T
)
```

Note that in the toy example the resultant LCP (that goes south-east then south-west) is the same cost as if the LCP went directly south to the destination location. Therefore, both routes are technically the least-cost path. I need to see how the igraph shortest.path decides which one to return (and also check if I've made it so that only one is returned in the *create_lcp()* function.

Comment: (1) In your own code, you do not compute `1/m` and you provide directly `cost.r` into `create_cs()`, as I do in my code. So, what's the right procedure?

(2) Regardless of what function of `conductanceMatrix` is actually plotted, the only cost minimizing path between the two points in my MWE is a straight line. That is because of two concomitants reasons: (i) by moving south-east instead of south, the path reaches a more costly pixel; (ii) even if the pixels were equally costly, moving on a diagonal involves more cost than moving on a straight line.

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Apologies. You'll need to do 1/m to convert cost to conductance. This was a copy/paste error.

(i) the two different ways (south and south-east) both have a cost of 1. So these are equivalent cost-wise.

(ii) The current implementation of create_cs does not correct for distance. This is something I need to add to the code. The create_cs() directly replicates the values provided in the spatRaster.

Comment: As per the use of conductance instead of cost rasters, you should probably edit the code in your answer to avoid confusion for future readers. Also, I feel that this clarification should be made more explicit in the package manual via a brief explanation and a related working example.